# Coax cable loss drops by approximately 0.5 dB at a specific frequency

Tags: rf, cables, coax, loss

I am trying to understand why the measured loss of our coaxial cable is decreased exactly at a specific frequency. My understanding is that the loss should be linear with the frequency. However, there is a strange drop which I cannot explain to myself. (The two lines are two different cables, but from exactly the same supplier and type.)

Cable loss vs. frequency:
[image: cable loss vs. frequency]

Does anyone have an explanation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To give a good answer, without any guessing, we will need to know your exact measurement setup, what equipment was used and how. Also how did you calibrate the measurement setup. You're assuming that the cables have the weird behavior around, what I assume is, 1800 MHz. Are you sure that it is not your measurement setup? Can you prove that the response of your setup itself is flat?

Comment: Standing waves due to not correctly terminating the cable.

Comment: Try connecting both cables in series, and show that measurement result on the same graph, would give extra clues if the length of the cable at a particular frequency is significant.

Comment: More details of your test setup would help.
1) What type of test gear are you using? A network analyzer?
2) What length of cable are you measuring?
3) Are you sure you have terminations where needed?

Comment: How long are the cables? They look pretty short to me - cable loss is easier to measure when you have 10 m or 100 m, than 1 m or 0.1 m.  Are all your connectors new, high quality, clean, torqued correctly? Cheap, dirty, worn-out or loose connectors will do this. Is the dip stable even when you wiggle all the wires?